# How to prepend one element to another, ahead of existing content, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

My DOM tree looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    **insert new p here**
    <p></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

How do I append an element to the div, so that it always appears before the initial p element, therefore stacking on top of subsequent p elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the inserted `<p></p>` to be the first child of the `<div></div>`, you can use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/). In your case it would look like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="paras">
    <p>World</p>
  </div>

  <script src="path/to/jquery"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#paras').prepend('<p>Hello</p>');
  </script>
</body>
```

If in fact you just would like to put it above that `<p></p>` and there are going to be other elements above it, you should use nicael's answer.

Comment: thanks! i always thought prepend would put the the paragraph ABOVE div. silly me

Answer (score 0):

In the case if you add new `<p>`s,  there will be many `<p>` tags, so I recommend you to assign an id to it.

E.g.:

```
<body>
  <div>
**insert new p here**
   <p id="main">
   </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then the code would be:

```
$( "<p>something there</p>" ).insertBefore( "p#main" );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options, other than those already listed; for completism (or as near as I'm able to get):

#### jQuery:

Using `prepend()`:

```
// creates a new <p> element
var newElement = $('<p>', {
  // sets its text to 'Hello'
  // (internally using the text() method):
  'text' : 'Hello'
});

// sets prepends the created-<p> to the
// elements matched by the selector:
$('div').prepend(newElement);
```

```js
var newElement = $('<p>', {
  'text': 'Hello'
});

$('div').prepend(newElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- insert new p here -->
  <p>
    World
  </p>
</div>
```

Using `prependTo()`:

```
$('<p>', {
  'text' : 'Hello'
// prepending to the each <div> element:
}).prependTo('div');
```

```js
$('<p>', {
  'text': 'Hello'
}).prependTo('div');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- insert new p here -->
  <p>
    World
  </p>
</div>
```

Using `before()`:

```
var newElement = $('<p>', {
  'text' : 'Hello'
});

// inserts the created-<p> before all elements
// matched by the selector:
$('p').before(newElement);
```

```js
var newElement = $('<p>', {
  'text': 'Hello'
});

$('p').before(newElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- insert new p here -->
  <p>
    World
  </p>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

Using `parentNode.insertBefore()`:

```
// creating a <p> element:
var newElement = document.createElement('p'),
  // reference to the (first) <div> element in
  // the document:
  div = document.querySelector('div');

// setting the textContent of the created-<p>:
newElement.textContent = 'Hello';

// inserting the created-<p> element before the
// firstChild of the <div> element we found (above):
div.insertBefore(newElement, div.firstChild);
```

```js
var newElement = document.createElement('p'),
  div = document.querySelector('div');
newElement.textContent = 'Hello';

div.insertBefore(newElement, div.firstChild);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- insert new p here -->
  <p>
    World
  </p>
</div>
```

Using `Node.insertAdjacentHTML()`:

```
// finding the first <p> element in the document:
var p = document.querySelector('p');

// inserting the supplied HTML string before
// that found-<p> element,
// strings:
//  'beforebegin': before the element itself,
//  'afterbegin': before the first existing child-node,
//  'beforeend': after the last existing child-node,
//  'afterend': after the element itself:
p.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<p>Hello</p>');
```

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');

p.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<p>Hello</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- insert new p here -->
  <p>
    World
  </p>
</div>
```

Using `Node.insertAdjacentHTML()` again, but with 'afterbegin'

```
// finding the first <div> element in the document:
var div = document.querySelector('div');

// inserting the supplied HTML inside of the found <div>,
// before its existing content:
div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>Hello</p>');
```

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>Hello</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- insert new p here -->
  <p>
    World
  </p>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
  - [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).
  - [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- jQuery:

  - [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).
  - [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
  - [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).
  - [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).